# Adjust container over a image using position

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

I am building a NextJs web app using chakra ui and tailwind, I have a Image that takes up the whole width available and I want to position a container on that image on specific postion. I am able to do this on large screens but when it goes on mobile, that container covers the whole image and some content around it.
[How it is on large screens and how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jczrK.jpg)
[How it is on mobile, you can see it has covered the whole image and some content around it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnlrZ.png)

Here is my code

```
<Grid templateColumns="repeat(6, 1fr)" className="pb-52">
{* other grid items *}
<GridItem
  colSpan={6}
  className="flex justify-center items-center relative"
>
  <Image src={feature} className="pt-20 px-4" alt="featured work" />
  <GridItem
    colSpan={6}
    className="p-14 absolute -bottom-32 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 w-full md:w-auto"
    maxW="800px"
    style={{
      background: "linear-gradient(315deg, #0FB81B 0%, #129A8E 100%)",
    }}
  >
    <Text className="text-2xl font-bold text-white pb-3">
      Our Own Product
    </Text>
    <Text
      className="text-5xl font-bold text-white pb-7"
      style={{ letterSpacing: "-1px" }}
    >
      Where there is cricket, there is CricksLab!
    </Text>
    <Button
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        color: "#FE7701",
        fontSize: "16px",
        fontWeight: "bold",
      }}
      className="p-7"
      rightIcon={<Image src={arrowRightUpOrange} alt="arrow right up" />}
    >
      View Case Study
    </Button>
  </GridItem>
</GridItem>
{* other grid items *}
</Grid>
```

I have tried so many ways to get this done but i can not figure out a way, please help me out. I am new to this and stuck here for days.